# Saving and loading BERT model in R

Tags: r, keras, bert-language-model

I used [this tutorial](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-09-30-bert-r/) to partially train a model (pretrained BERT) on some text data. Except from data, all other code is the same.

I have problems saving and loading the trained model. If I use the following code:

```
save_model_hdf5(model, "model.h5")
model2 <- load_model_hdf5("model.h5")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Unknown layer: TokenEmbedding
```

How can I succesfully save and load the model?